# Cross entropy of continuous conditional probability?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, information-theory

What is the cross entropy between the continuous conditional probability $ p(z|x) $ and the probability $r(z)$?
Should it be:
$$ CH(p(z|x),r(z))=-\int\int p(z|x)log\left(r(z)\right)dxdz $$ 
Or:
$$ CH(p(z|x),r(z))=-\int\int p(z,x)log\left(r(z)\right)dxdz $$ 
Or maybe something else?

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.